# Accessing nginx behind a Virtual Server looses port number

Tags: nginx, port-forwarding

I have a Debian server running nginx with the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  root /var/www/serviceserver1;
  index index.html index.htm;      

  location /api {
        proxy_redirect          http://localhost:3001/  /api;
        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;

        proxy_pass              http://localhost:3001;
    }

    location /graphql {
        proxy_redirect          http://localhost:3001/  /graphql;
        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;

        proxy_pass              http://localhost:3001;
   }

  # Root route
  location = / {
    try_files $uri /landing/index.html;
  }

  # admin routes
  location /admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html;
  }

  # analytics routes
  location /analytics {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /analytics/index.html;
  }

  # landing routes
  location /landing {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /landing/index.html;
  }

  # Any other route default to landing
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /landing/index.html;
  }
}
```

Works very fine in my LAN.

I'm now setting up an external connection to the Internet. I'm using a TP-LINK TL-R470T+ with a Virtual Server configuration to redirect my ports (8000 from outside goes to 80 internally):

[image]

When I try to access my browser from outsite, I use:

http://170.80.200.100:8000/landing/

All fine.

My problem arises when I need to switch pages on my Web applcation. Every time I navigate, I'm getting back to the url without the port, like (Ip address not the real one):

http://170.80.200.100/landing/

http://170.80.200.100/admin/

or

http://170.80.200.100/analytics/

So, every time I navigate to a different page I need to type the :8000 by hand in the address bar, something impractical.

How can I setup my NGINX file to keep the original port back (:8000) on every URL acessed, when I'm accessing from the internet?

---

Note that I've tried changing the internal port from 80 to 8000 and application worked perfectly when accessed on that port from the internal LAN, but I cannot keep it set to 8000 internally and need it set to 8000 externally.

Comment: Are you asking how to get Nginx to edit your html files and add the `:8000` string to any links? You may be able to use [`sub_filter`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter).

Comment: I'm not asking that, the opposite. I need to make the system work on port redirection without touching my html files...